# How do you scan multiple strings in all containing spaces?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to scan in strings one after another and some may contain spaces. As my code functions currently it will only work if each string you type in is one word. What's the proper way to scan in consecutive lines of text, regardless of there being spaces in the line or not.

```
System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
                fName = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
                lName = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your street and house number: ");
                address = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your city: ");
                city = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your state: ");
                state = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your telephone number (no spaces): ");
                teleNum = scan.next();

                System.out.print("Enter your zip code: ");
                zip = scan.next();
```

Comment: I like using BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)), but I am not really sure of the advantages/disadvantages/differences to these two methods. If you are using a bufferedreader, it is br.readLine

Comment: Forgot to mention I also tried nextLine with no luck.. Buffered reader seems like a viable option.

Comment: can you post your actual code somewhere? maybe https://gist.github.com/ ?    nextLine is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] prompts = {
        "Enter your city: ",
        "Enter your state: ",
    };

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "";
    for (String prompt : prompts) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
            line += scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(line);
```